# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm newbie to `backbone.js` and `underscore.js`.

HTML :

```
<div id="cartlist">
<script type="text/template" id="cart_template">

</script>
</div>
```

Where I called the view file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcore/views/CartView.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS function(it works well with the javascript project):

```
 function Cart(){
    ......
    this.showCart = function (){
    var item = deserializeJSONToObj(window.localStorage.getItem(Cart.storageName));
    var str = '<table id="showcart">';
    str += '<tr><td class="cartitemhead">Item to buy</td><td class="cartitemhead" style="text-align: center;">Quantity</td></tr>';
    $.each(item, function(i, item) {
        str += '<tr><td><table class="verticallist"><tr><td rowspan="4" style="width: 120px;"><img src="' + item.PictureName + '" alt="Product" width="95px"/></td><td style="font-weight: bold;">'+trimString(item.Name,50)+'</td></tr><tr><td><i>Available in Stock(s)!</i></td></tr><tr><td><i>Rating:   650Va-390w Input:   Single</i></td></tr></table></td><td class="centertxt">'+item.QuantityInCart+'</td></tr>';
    });
    str += '</table>';
    return str;
 }
```

This is the Views :

```
var myCart = new Cart();
CartList = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize:function(){
    this.render();
},
render: function(){
    var template = _.template( $("#cart_template").html(), {} );
    this.$el.html( template );
}
});
var cart_view = new CartList({ el: $("#cartlist").html(myCart.showCart()) });
```

1. when I trying to call the view template, I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined - underscore.js`. Please help me to find the mistake.
2. How can I convert `str` string in `Cart` class to a `template` of `underscore.js`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi.Did you find a solution for this?
I am stuck in the similar situation.

Answer (score 11):

I'd guess that your problem is where you're storing `#cart_template` in the DOM:

```
<div id="cartlist">
    <script type="text/template" id="cart_template">
    </script>
</div>
```

You create your `CartList` like this:

```
var cart_view = new CartList({ el: $("#cartlist").html(myCart.showCart()) });
```

When you say this:

```
$("#cartlist").html(myCart.showCart())
```

everything that was inside `#cartlist` is gone, in particular, `#cart_template` is gone. Then inside `CartList`, you try to do this:

```
_.template( $("#cart_template").html(), {} );
```

But there is no more `#cart_template` at that point so `$('#cart_template').html()` is `undefined` and that's where your error comes from: `_.template` will call `replace` internally but you're giving it `undefined` as the template instead of a string.

The solution is to move your `#cart_template` outside `#cartlist`.

I'd also recommend that you not pass the `el` to the view's constructor, your view should create its own `el` and the caller should put that `el` where it wants it in the DOM. That way the view is wholly responsible for its element and you'll have fewer zombie and event problems.

Comment: I tried to change `<div id="cartlist"></div><script type="text/template" id="cart_template"/>` but there nothing display in UI. And could you give me an example of `your view should create its own el and the caller should put that el where it wants it in the DOM` please. Thanks.

Comment: But your template is empty so why would anything display? The Backbone documentation and the standard TODOs example should show you how to set up a view that creates its own `el`.

Comment: It is working while I did this `render: function(){  this.$el.html(myCart.showCart()); }` and `var cart_view = new CartList({ el: $("#cartlist") });`.

Comment: Put your backbone code inside the $(document).ready() method to insure that the DOM is ready so $('#cart_template') is accessible then the backbone code will be executed

Comment: @hamism: Not in this case. The problem here is that the template is inside the DOM node that is the view's `el`, then the content of `el` is replaced and that destroys the DOM node that contains the template.